# Como carregar javascript corretamente de forma dinâmica

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Eu tenho duas páginas chamadas header.html e footer.html. Elas são incluídas em todas as páginas via javascript. Para o header funcionar corretamente e o menu abrir quando eu passar o mouse eu utilizo o script bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js, mas esse menu só funciona corretamente se eu incluir esse script do bootstrap direto no header.html, mas se eu fizer isso, ao carregar a página index.html, aparecem conflitos no console do navegador pelo fato de carregar scripts do header e do index. Se eu colocar para carregar o script do bootstrap na página index, o menu não abre ao passar o mouse.

Em resumo, o menu do header.html não enxerga esta tag que está inserido em index.html:

```
<script src="assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js"></script>
```

E assim o menu não funciona, mas se eu colocar esta tag no header.html o menu funciona, mas aparecem conflitos de script no console do navegador.

Alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Comment: Olá @cesarpereira014, sua pergunta está um pouco ampla. Por favor, insira mais informações, de preferência o código de sua página para que possamos lhe ajudar. Aproveite e veja na [help] no link [ask].

Comment: como você esta fazendo o include do header.html e footer ? usando a função load ?

Comment: Carrega todos os JS no final da sua index, ja tentou? Recomendo que você veja como usar o requieJs, pode ser algo util para você.
[inserir a descrição do link aqui](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: É através da função load sim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode carregar o seu arquivo `header.html` como você ja faz no load() e quando estiver carregado você carrega sua script com getScript, veja o exemplo:

```js
$("#resultado").load("header.html", function() {
  // arquivo header.html carregado.
  var boostrapHover = 'assets/global/plugins/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js';
  $.getScript(boostrapHover, function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
    // arquivo bootstrap-hover-dropdown.js carregado.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: Funcionou! Muito obrigado