# Adicionar código antes da </head> e depois da <body>

Tags: javascript

Preciso de um cogido javascript que adicione este código antes do fechamento da tag `</head>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.grupospotlight.com/nav/navbar.css">
```

E este logo depois da tag `<body>`

```
    <ul class="spot-nav">
        <li class="left spot-logo">
          <a class="spot-a"><div class="spot-logo"/></a>
        </li>
        <li class="right">
            <a class="spot-a" href="http://www.grupospotlight.com/" target="_blank">WWW.GRUPOSPOTLIGHT.COM</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Qual é a necessidade de adicionar com um JavaScript e não diretamente no arquivo? Vai ser carregado dinamicamente após uma ação do usuário?

Comment: ⇨ http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97176/como-carregar-javascript-corretamente-de-forma-din%C3%A2mica

Comment: ⇨ http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/114647/carregar-javascript-de-uma-url-atrav%C3%A9s-da-barra-de-endere%C3%A7os-ou-bookmarklet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode usar `document.createElement` com `appendChild` e `insertBefore`, para inserir faça isto pode fazer assim:

```
//Esta função é mais rapida que usar window.onload
function readyDom(callback) {
    if (/^(interactive|complete)$/i.test(document.readyState)) {
        callback();
    } else {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", callback);
    }
}

//vai inserir dentro do head antes do </head>
readyDom(function() {
    var navbar = document.createElement("link");

    navbar.rel  = "stylesheet";
    navbar.type = "text/css";
    navbar.href = "http://cdn.grupospotlight.com/nav/navbar.css";

    document.head.appendChild(navbar);
});

//vai no <body>, antes de qualquer elemento
readyDom(function() {
    var ulnav = document.createElement("ul");

    ulnav.className = "spot-nav";

    ulnav.innerHTML = '<li class="left spot-logo">' +
                      '<a class="spot-a"><div class="spot-logo"></div></a>' +
                      '</li>' +
                      '<li class="right">' +
                      '<a class="spot-a" href="http://www.grupospotlight.com/" target="_blank">WWW.GRUPOSPOTLIGHT.COM</a>' +
                      '</li>';

    document.body.insertBefore(ulnav, document.body.firstChild);
});
```

Se precisar de um delay use `setTimeout`:

```
//vai no <body>, antes de qualquer elemento
readyDom(function() {
    var segundos = 3; //3 segundos

    setTimeout(function() {
        var ulnav = document.createElement("ul");

        ulnav.className = "spot-nav";

        ulnav.innerHTML = '<li class="left spot-logo">' +
                          '<a class="spot-a"><div class="spot-logo"></div></a>' +
                          '</li>' +
                          '<li class="right">' +
                          '<a class="spot-a" href="http://www.grupospotlight.com/" target="_blank">WWW.GRUPOSPOTLIGHT.COM</a>' +
                          '</li>';

        document.body.insertBefore(ulnav, document.body.firstChild);
    }, 1000 * segundos);
});
```

Recomendo que estude sobre DOM:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model

Comment: Só um detalhe, o link com `http://` é entendido como comentário pelo javascript, talvez seja melhor utilizar aspas simples?

Comment: @GabrielRanéaBarbosa obrigado, foi erro de digitação mesmo.

Comment: Tem como fazer com que o código que vem depois do <body> carregue 3 segundos depois do que vem antes do </head>?

Comment: @Nano_OFF pode-se usar `setTimeout`, eu editei a resposta e deixei um exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Utlizando jQuery fica bem mais simples.

Poderia usar a função [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/), para inserir no "head", assim:

```
$("head").append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://cdn.grupospotlight.com/nav/navbar.css'>");
```

E a função [.prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) para inserir logo depois da tag body, assim:

```
$("body").prepend("<ul class='spot-nav'> <li class='left spot-logo'><a class='spot-a'><div class='spot-logo'/></a></li><li class='right'><a class='spot-a' href='http://www.grupospotlight.com/'' target='_blank'>WWW.GRUPOSPOTLIGHT.COM</a></li></ul>");
```

Comment: Um bom exemplo de uso se a pessoa já usa jQuery, mas importar uma biblioteca inteira para fazer apenas inserção de dois elementos DOM parece desperdício.